# Is it possible to prevent Visual Studio to break on exception inside BackgroudWorker.DoWork

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

The problem is that the application is supposed to handle errors that occur inside [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) in a certain way. In a published version of my app, I'm generating an error in purpose to test it and is not doing what it is supposed to do, but if I debug then VS will break at the exception instead of passing it to `RunWorkerCompleted` which is what would happen after published (or when not running under the VS debugger) according to the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) documentation. Is there any way to prevent VS from stopping at the exception and make it do what it would do after published while debugging so I can see what's wrong with my code?

@ChrisF: Here's my code. I don't think it will help much:

```
    void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(null == e.Error) OnDownloadComplete(new DownloadCompleteEventArgs(e.Cancelled, null, e.Result as string));
        else OnDownloadComplete(new DownloadCompleteEventArgs(false, e.Error, null));
    }

    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("OMG!!!");
    }
```

If is not possible to do what I'm trying to do I can try to find another way to find my error. I don't think is a good idea to post more code since it gets pretty entangled in `OnDownloadComplete` and the error can be anywhere. Just need to discard the possibility to debug first.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code.

Comment: I know there is a attribute you can decorate your DoWork method with to let the exception run it's course. Was it `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` or `[DebuggerHidden]`?...can't remember...

Comment: Why not just set a breakpoint or even a conditional breakpoint rather than throwing an exception? (BTW, the code was helpful in clarifying your question).

Comment: @ChrisF I think OP wants the exception to bubble up to the RunWorkerCompleted event and not be caught by the VS debugger...

Comment: @dotjoe - it appears I still missed the point of the question then.

Comment: @dotjoe: `[DebuggerHidden]` did it. You should post it as an answer so I can accept it. @ChrisF: Yes, what dotjoe said is what I needed. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough ;)

Comment: I"m trying to do the exact opposite, for some reason the debugger is not stopping when an exception is thrown in my backgroundworker thread, and I need it to... there must be a setting somewhere causing this, I have no attributes to prevent it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DebuggerHidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a4d38ze%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

can be used here to let the exception bubble up to the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Answer (score 2):

This is sure to be a duplicate, but anyway... you should open the dialog Debug/Exceptions... in visual studio, lookup the exception you want VS to ignore, and disable the 'thrown' checkbox.